# Excel VBA - extraordinary WinHttpRequest.Open error for only a few of url

Tags: vba

Checking some URLs with

```
Function SiteStatus(ByVal URL As String, SiteStatusText As String) As Long

    Dim oHttp As New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest

    oHttp.Option(WinHttpRequestOption_EnableRedirects) = False

    oHttp.Open "GET", URL, False
    oHttp.Send

    SiteStatus = oHttp.Status
    SiteStatusText = oHttp.StatusText

End Function
```

generally works fine. Only a few URLs throw a VBA error -2147012744. The Server is giving an invalid or unknown response.
Some URLs in real work, I can open them with SHDocVw library, and some not, - that makes no difference.
for instance:

```
http: //s2.excoboard.com/Courthouse_Steps_Mavens/150601/1831324
```

or

```
http: //www.geld-und-leben.com/anleitung/
```

or

```
http: //globalnews.ca/news/3025046/justin-timberlakes-illegal-voting-booth-selfie-is-under-review/
```

I wanna check the status of these sites although.
How?
What's the point?

Answer (score 2):

i know that this is old, but here is some VBA code that works.

some of the values for oHttp.Option came from http://www.808.dk/?code-simplewinhttprequest

```
Sub test()

    ' add reference to Microsoft WinHTTP Services

    Dim URL As String
    URL = "http://globalnews.ca/news/3025046/justin-timberlakes-illegal-voting-booth-selfie-is-under-review"

    Dim oHttp As WinHttpRequest
    Set oHttp = New WinHttpRequest

    oHttp.Open "GET", URL, False

    oHttp.Option(WinHttpRequestOption_UserAgentString) = "http_requester/0.1"
    oHttp.Option(WinHttpRequestOption_SslErrorIgnoreFlags) = &H3300            '  ignore all err, 0: accept no err
    oHttp.Option(WinHttpRequestOption_EnableRedirects) = True
    oHttp.Option(WinHttpRequestOption_EnableHttpsToHttpRedirects) = True

    oHttp.send

    Do While True
        DoEvents
        If oHttp.Status Then Exit Do
    Loop

    Debug.Print oHttp.Status

End Sub
```